# Visual (drag-n-drop) tool to design mobile apps using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, ide

For MacOS, there is a [free visual design & development tool](http://www.vinisketch.com/features.html), however I've not managed to find anything similar available on Windows or Linux, so wanted to check if there is indeed no such tool. Free would be ideal, as I am experimenting, but small pay-as-you-go would be acceptable too.

The functionality I am looking for, graphical composition of the mobile application UI as set of "screens" (or "Activities") and then being able to define the "event-driven" logic s.a. what happens on button presses, timeouts, message arrival etc. If that is something expressed in abstract higher-level form, that is okay, else okay with it being in Javascript as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap applications' UI is just HTML/CSS/JS running in a web browser view that takes the 100% of the screen.
On iOS is a UIWebView, on Android is a webkit.WebView.
So actually you cannot think as "screens" and "activities" but you can simply use the tools you use to build "normal" web applications.

EDIT: [here](http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/) a simple but very good explanation.